# Lightswitch - Cannot update application

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch Application (3 Tier, Desktop) that I am trying to get running, however the following error is preventing me from moving forward.

[image]

The application was working before, but for some reason today it just does not want to install.

After deleting the site/contents from IIS, clearing my browsers cache, uninstalling the application, cleaning the project and publishing the application from Visual Studio I receive the error screen. This happens right off the bat, after the application installs, and opens for the first time.

It's curious because the application's xap has not been signed in the publish settings. I am wondering what could be the cause of this? I have not seen anything unusual in \Trace.axd

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign the xap with a certificate.
It can be, for testing, a self-signed certificate, which you store manually in the local certificate store.

Comment: The xap signing does not work for me either, which is why I am not signing the xap. I'd like to sign the xap but I keep getting similar errors.

Comment: In fact I have just tried it, and I get the same exact error.

Comment: It seems to be a Google Chrome issue. Because when I use internet explorer this problem goes away.